# Drop down sub-menu is opening horizontally instead of vertically.

Tags: html, css

I am learning HTML5 and CSS. So my question is probably very basic and very naive. My apology for that.
To practice I am developing a header menu with drop down sub menu. The problem that I am experiencing is that even though I set up the display value of the sub-menu to block so that the sub-menu drops down vertically but now it drops horizontally. 
html file :

```
       <nav>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="#">All</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">New Arrival</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Casual</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Gown</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Bridesmade</a></li>
                </ul>
              <li><a href="#">Woman</a></li>
                  <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">All</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">New Arrival</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Casual</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Gown</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Bridesmade</a></li>
                  </ul>
              <li>
              <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
```

here is the css code:

```
nav{
  height:40px;
  width: 960px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0,auto;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

nav a{
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #112233;
}

nav ul{
  list-style: none;
}

nav ul li{
  float:left;
  width:140px;
  height:40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  background: #fc575e;
}

nav ul ul li{
  position: relative;
  display: none;
}

nav ul li:hover + ul li{
  display: block;  
}

nav ul li:hover{
  background-color: #223433;
  color:#f0f1f5;
}
```

I was wondering if some body could help me out what is wrong with my code? It is really appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

The corrections are.

1. The issue was because the `li` tag were all `float:left`, this caused even the dropdown elements to be horizontal. So I created a class `.dropdown` to reset the float to none.

**CSS:**

```
.dropdown li {
  float: none;
}
```

2. The dropdown `ul` tag, will still cause issues with the layout because you are not setting it to absolute position which will keep it separate from the navbar and show it as a floating (not CSS float) kind of element. Then the `ul.dropdown` needs to be placed inside the parent `li` element. This will allow us to position the absolute element according to the parent `li` element.

**CSS:**

```
nav ul li {
  float: left;
  position:relative;
  width: 140px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  background: #fc575e;
}

.dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0px;
  padding-left:0px;
}
```

3. On hovering the `a` tags were also in black which made the label dissapear. I recommend adding the CSS below, which will set the `a` tag to white color, on hover alone.

**CSS:**

```
nav ul li:hover > a {
  color: white;
}
```

Finally below is a working example of the code.

```css
nav {
  height: 40px;
  width: 960px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0, auto;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

nav a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #112233;
}

nav ul {
  list-style: none;
}

nav ul li {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  width: 140px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  background: #fc575e;
}

nav ul li ul li {
  position: relative;
  display: none;
}

nav ul li:hover>a {
  color: white;
}

nav ul li:hover ul li {
  display: block;
}

nav ul li:hover {
  background-color: #223433;
  color: #f0f1f5;
}

.dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0px;
  padding-left: 0px;
}

.dropdown li {
  float: none;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Home</a>
      <ul class="dropdown">
        <li><a href="#">All</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">New Arrival</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Casual</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Gown</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Bridesmade</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li>
      <a href="#">Woman</a>
      <ul class="dropdown">
        <li><a href="#">All</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">New Arrival</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Casual</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Gown</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Bridesmade</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: @user1836957 Can this answer be closed? or are you facing any issues?

Answer (score 0):

```
1.Avoid the plus (+) sign in nav ul li:hover + ul li{display: block;} style.

2.Add one more style nav ul li ul {padding-left: 0px;}

3.li tag of Home and Woman close after dropdown list items. i.e,
<li><a href="#">Home</a>
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">All</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">New Arrival</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Casual</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Gown</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Bridesmade</a></li>
</ul>
</li>

Corrupted code:
<html>
<head>
<style>
nav{
height:40px;
width: 960px;
display: block;
margin: 0,auto;
text-align: center;
text-transform: uppercase;
}

nav a{
display: block;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 13px;
color: #112233;
}

nav ul{
list-style: none;
}

nav ul li{
float:left;
width:140px;
height:40px;
line-height: 40px;
background: #fc575e;
}

nav ul ul li{
position: relative;
display: none;
}

nav ul li:hover  ul li{
display: block;  
}

nav ul li:hover{
background-color:  #e3b0b2;
color:#f0f1f5;
}
nav ul li ul{
padding-left: 0px;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">All</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">New Arrival</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Casual</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Gown</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Bridesmade</a></li>
        </ul>
        </li>
      <li><a href="#">Woman</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">All</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">New Arrival</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Casual</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Gown</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Bridesmade</a></li>
          </ul>
          </li>
      <li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</body>
</html>
```